# Разработать класс Товар

Tags: php

Нужно создать класс Товар: название, цена, поставщик. От него 2 наследуемых класса: цифровой товар (добавляется поле емкость в мб) и печатный товар(добавляется поле автор)

```
<?php
namespace Allproduct;

class Product
{
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $provider;

    function __construct($name, $price, $provider)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    class PrintedProduct extends Product
    {
       public $author;

    function __construct($name, $price, $provider, $author)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $price, $provider);
        $this->author = $author;
    }
    
}

class DigitalProduct extends Product
{
    public $capacity;

    function __construct($name, $price, $provider, $capacity)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $price, $provider);
        $this->capacity = $capacity;
    }
    
 }   
}
?>
```

Класс сделал, наследуемые тоже. Не много не понимаю формулировку продолжение задания: 
 Все классы должны позволять вводить значения свойств,
получать значения свойств, вычислять скидку для товара. Создать по два
экземпляра каждого класса, используя конструкторы и вывести на страницу
товары всех типов.  
Что значит выводить\получать значение свойств? это что за метод? как посчитать скидку если дана только цена?

Comment: Поля класса должны быть private или protected, а не public. Тогда для доступа к ним, нужно делать методы - геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: @ArchDemon понял, а что по поводу скидки?

Comment: Слишком мало входной информации чтобы считать скидку. И ещё одно замечание, не создавайте классы в классах. Один файл - один класс. Psr-4 загрузчик работает именно так